# Split time series data in Train and test set with year selection in R

Tags: r

At present I am using this but it is not giving write figure after for test set

```
p <- read.csv("steel.csv")
p$Date= parse_date_time(p$Date, "mdy")

train=ts(p$data,c(2014,1),c(2019,06),12)
test=ts(p$data,c(2019,07),c(2020,06),12)
```

any solution please. also can be used in shiny

Comment: Hi Akrun, thank for the reply, you I used your code but it is given blank output

Comment: Date price
01/01/2014 0.749788188
02/01/2014 0.778364507
03/01/2014 0.789250724
04/01/2014 0.827806075
05/01/2014 0.915802995
06/01/2014 1.059591776
07/01/2014 1.070477993
08/01/2014 1.071385178
09/01/2014 1.055055853
10/01/2014 1.062313331
11/01/2014 0.938029021
12/01/2014 0.879062013
p <- read.csv("steel.csv")
p$Date= parse_date_time(p$Date, "mdy")

h <- subset(p,Date >= as.POSIXct('01-01-2014') &
                           Date <= as.POSIXct('12-01-2014'))


View(h)
can it help you

Comment: even if I use your code result are blank 
p <- read.csv("steel.csv")
p$Date= parse_date_time(p$Date, "mdy")

train_dat <- subset(p, Date > as.Date('2014-01-01') & Date < as.Date('2019-06-12'))

Comment: akrun thanks your last code work, I was stuck in this for day hope it will work in shiny to but thank you so much, you really saved me. please put your solution for the community

Comment: Please take some time to review the advice here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. Your question is not reproducible and doesn't give us enough information to help you.

Answer (score 1):

To subset an object of class `"ts"`, use [`window`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/window.html).

```
## Using January 2014 as start date:
set.seed(2022)

x <- cumsum(1 + round(rnorm(78), 2))
x <- ts(x, start = c(2014, 1), frequency = 12)

train <- window(x, start = c(2014, 1), end = c(2019, 6))
test <- window(x, start = c(2019, 07), end = c(2020, 6))
```